# numeric integration as a input for other function

Tags: numerical-integration

```
s = NDSolve[{r'[t] -Sqrt[(-10^-6 r[t]^2 + 1) (10^-2 + Sqrt[-10^-6 +
       r[t]^-2])] == 0,r[0] == 0.01}, r, {t, -0.2, 1.389}];
```

I want to use a numeric integration solution (relation between `r` and `t`) given above as a input for the expression given below:

```
p = (r^(-3/2)Sqrt[(-10^-6 r^2 + 1) (10^-2 r + Sqrt[-10^-6 r^2 + 1])])/10^3
```

Comment: In `p` the Symbol `r` is not used as a function but rather a constant.  How are you intending to apply a function in its place?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We will get a relation between r and t from NDSolve and I want to incorporate this relation into the expression given by p which is a function of r. So that I can plot p as a function of t.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you want something like this:

```
p2[t_] := Block[{r = s[[1, 1, 2]][t]}, p]

Plot[p2[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Be aware that function `p2` depends on the persistent definitions of `s` and `p`.  If you want a stand-alone function, meaning you are free to [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) or change `s` and `p` then use perhaps:

```
(p3[t_] := With[{r = #[t]}, #2]) &[s[[1, 1, 2]], p]
```

---

#### Considerations

[corey979](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/22013/corey979) provides a simpler [solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/136083/121) using a more direct replacement.  I chose not to post that method when I realized it would produce a function of the form:

[image]

Here the [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) is copied multiple times, and when the function is used it will be evaluated multiple times.  *This may or may not matter to you.*  However I prefer the cleaner form that my code produces:

[image]

(The images above are captured from the output of [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues.html))

Comment: Yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
s = r /. NDSolve[{r'[t] - Sqrt[(-10^-6 r[t]^2 + 1) (10^-2 + Sqrt[-10^-6 + r[t]^-2])] == 0,
  r[0] == 0.01}, r, {t, -0.2, 1.389}][[1]]

p[t_] = (r^(-3/2) Sqrt[(-10^-6 r^2 + 1) (10^-2 r + Sqrt[-10^-6 r^2 + 1])])/10^3 /. r -> s[t];

Plot[p[t], {t, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: A problem with this simpler approach is that you end up evaluating the InterpolatingFunction once for every appearance of `r`.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard True, but 1) I feel this is more in the spirit of the OP, and 2) it's good to show it.